# Get "next" numeric value in object

Tags: javascript, sorting, object

I have an object like this:

```
var rock = {
 5: 0.5,
 0: 0.8,
 10: 0.3,
 2: 1.0,
}
```

I have a number like `4.3`and I need the index and value of the prior and following numer. In this example I would get

```
var timeA = 2;
var valueA = 1.0
var timeB = 5;
var valueB = 0.5;
```

My first idea was something like a for-loop, but I don't know how to make sure that it's in the right order.

Comment: You have an object, so the order of your values is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the key ordering of objects isn't guaranteed, you'd have to iterate over all keys and work out the closest lower and higher value:

```
var rock = {
 0: 0.8,
 2: 1.0,
 5: 0.5,
 10: 0.3
};

var max = Infinity, min = -Infinity;
var to_find = 4.3;

Object.keys(rock).forEach(function(k) {
  var value = +k;

  if (value <= to_find && value > min) {
      min = value;
  } else if (value >= to_find && value < max) {
      max = value;
  }
});

console.log(min, rock[min], max, rock[max]); // 2, 1, 5, 0.5
```

Note that afterwards `min` or `max` may still have their original values, i.e. `-Infinity` and `Infinity`, in which case `undefined` would be yielded when used as a key to `rock`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `for..in` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop in javascript to loop through the properties of an object. Using that you can test the property `name` against the given value. Once you have the two properties you can access the property values using them as indices.

```
var given = 4.3;
var timeA = null;
var timeB = null;
for(var e in rock){
    if(e > given){
        timeB = e;
        break;
    }
    timeA = e;    
}
var valueA = rock[timeA];
var valueB = rock[timeB];
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x4hzetw7/

If you wanted this work as you expect however you must find a way to sort the properties. To do that you can follow the link on one of the previous answers (using `Object.keys(obj)`).

```
var given = 4.3;
var timeA = null;
var timeB = null;
var keys = Object.keys(rock);
var sorted = keys.map(Number).sort(function(a,b) {return a[0]-b[0];});
for(var i = 0; i < sorted.length; i++){
    var e = keys[i];
    if(e > given){
        timeB = e;
        break;
    }
    timeA = e;    
}
var valueA = rock[timeA];
var valueB = rock[timeB];
```

Updated JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x4hzetw7/5/

Comment: This assumes the keys are ordered lowest to highest, but that's not guaranteed.

Comment: Since you're using `Object.keys()` you might as well use `Array.prototype.map()` et al instead of underscore :)

Comment: @Ja͢ck Thanks for the help, i feel at this point your answer should be accepted since you basically wrote both.

Comment: Thanks for the vote :) oh, you should do `.map(Number)` instead of `.map(parseInt)`.

Comment: Yes, you _must_ use `Number`.  You will get incorrect results if you use `parseInt` because the latter will attempt to use all three parameters passed to the callback.

Answer (score -2):

You can do something like this:

```
for (var i in rock) {
    if (rock.hasOwnProperty(i) && rock[i] !== null) {
        var val = rock[i];
        console.log("rock["+i+"] = ", val);
    }
};
```

But JS objects aren't natively sorted. You might want to look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467129/sort-javascript-object-by-key) to understand how it works and what you can do about it.

Comment: _rock_ is object, not an array, so it does not have method _forEach_

Comment: objects don't have a `forEach` method